# How to iterate the AWS WAF rule priority number via terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the below code snippet to create the rules dynamically for RuleGroup.

```
dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = toset(var.external_endpoints)

    content {
      name     = rule.value.name
      priority = rule.value.priority
      statement {
        byte_match_statement {
          positional_constraint = "STARTS_WITH"
          search_string         = rule.value.path
          field_to_match {
            uri_path {}
          }
          text_transformation {
            priority = 0
            type     = "NONE"
          }
        }
      }

      action {
        allow {}
      }

      visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        metric_name                = rule.value.name
        sampled_requests_enabled   = true
      }
    }
  }
```

Every time a new rule is added, I need to manually change the priority value for all the existing rules from the below variable block.

```
external_endpoints = [
    {"name" = "App1Access", "path" = "/api/", "priority" = 5},
    {"name" = "App2Access", "path" = "/random", "priority" = 6},
    {"name" = "App3Access", "path" = "/tech", "priority" = 7},
    {"name" = "App4Access", "path" = "/condition", "priority" = 8},
    {"name" = "App5Access", "path" = "/account-id", "priority" = 9},
    {"name" = "App6Access", "path" = "/password", "priority" = 10},
]
```

I think this can be done using the in-built terraform function `range`. But not sure of the implementation or if there is a straightforward approach.

Comment: So basically you want to automagically increment/decrement the previous priority of a rule?

Comment: @MarkoE Exactly. I may add or remove the rule anywhere between the existing lists. It's difficult to change the `priority` value if the number of rules is more.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way to do that. `range` sounds like a reasonable option, only it returns a list, and you are already looping over a map, so not sure how would you fetch the correct index there.

Comment: It's okay if the key/value pairs of `priority` can be managed outside of this map. Is it possible to do this way?

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted it is clear that priority increase by one with the index of the rules in the list. Then you can use this fact and automatically create the priority number:

```
locals {
  external_endpoints2 = [
    for idx, rule in var.external_endpoints: 
      merge(rule, {priority = idx + 5})
  ]
}
```

then use the new local variable in the for_each:

```
for_each = toset(local.external_endpoints2)
```